# Parallel streams in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As written in the documentation, parallel streams allow us to execute pipelines in parallel. now, consider the following simple example:

```
List<Integer> lst;
//initialiaziation of lst
lst.parallelStream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max();
```

So, does it mean that the pipeline is executed in parallel? If so, how many threads will execute the pipeline? It's kind of miracle that we just create a parallel stream and that's it... Stream framework will decide how many threads to create to execute.

Comment: First of all, this code doesn't compile. Second: Is there any question besides the awe that I too share of streams and concurrency?

Comment: The number of threads is, like most of the execution strategy, an implementation detail. But it is known that in Oracle’s JRE it will use the Fork/Join Framework which has a default concurrency level matching the number of CPU cores. However, the concurrency level is not always identical to the number of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ***OCP : Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer || Study Guide : Exam 1z0-809***

> [...] Depending on the number of CPUs available in your environment
>   the following is a possible output of the code using a parallel stream
>   [...] Even better, the results scale with the number of processors.
>   Scaling is the property that, as we add more resources such as CPUs,
>   the results gradually improve. [...]

---

To test it, you may want to use `peek` and print the `Thread.currentThread()`

```
int i = list.parallelStream()
            .peek(x -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()))
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .max().getAsInt();
```

For me, using 4 processors, I get exactly four thread working on it.